# Find out the values for which the function is continuous

Tags: calculus

here is the function

$$ g(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if} \;x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ x & \text{if} \;x \notin \mathbb{Q} \end{cases} $$

I want to find the values at which this is continuous. I think this is continuous only at $x=0$ and I was able to prove it using epsilon-delta definition. And I don't think its continuous anywhere else. So, I need to prove that, for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$

$$ \lim \limits_{x \to a} g(x) \ne g(a) \;\;\; \text{if}\; a \ne 0$$

But I am stuck here. Should I proceed with method of contradiction ?

Thanks

Comment: Might be helpful to break it up into two cases: $a\neq 0$ is rational, or $a$ is irrational. Then try to find a sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that $x_n\to a$ but $g(x_n) \not\to g(a)$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $a\neq0$ you may consider $\epsilon=\frac{|a|}{2}>0$.

Then does not exist $\delta>0$ such that $|x-a|<\delta$ implies $|g(x)-g(a)|<\epsilon$.

In fact, for any $\delta>0$ there exists an irracional number $y$ satisfying $|y-a|<\delta$; Since $g(y)=0$, that is, $\begin{align}|g(y)- g(a)|&=|0-a|\\&=|a|\\&>\frac{\epsilon}{2}\end{align}$

Comment: Are you using method of contradiction here?  Also, I know from density of irrationals that if $\delta > 0$, there is some $y \notin \mathbb{Q}$ such that $\delta > y > 0$. But I didn't get how you got $|y-a| < \delta$ ?

Comment: I just proved that if $a\neq0$ then $g$ is not continuous in $a$. The other question is simple: all open intervals of the line contains both rationals and irracionals numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $a=0$ and $(x_n) $ be any sequence such that $x_n \to 0 $

Then, $f(a) =0 $

If $f(x_n) =0 $ then done.

And in other case , $f(x_n)=x_n \to 0=f(0) $

Hence, $f$ is continuous at $0$

Suppose, $a\neq 0$ is rational.

Consider a sequence of irrational $(s_n) $ such that $s_n \to a$

Then, $f(s_n)=s_n \to a \neq 0=f(a) $

Suppose, $a\neq 0$ is irrational.

Consider a sequence of rational $(r_n) $ such that $r_n \to a$

Then, $f(r_n)\to 0 \neq a =f(a) $

Hence, the function $f$ is not continuous at any non zero point.

Comment: $SG, this problem is from Stewart's Calculus book Chapter 1 on limits. So, this machinery of sequences has not been developed at this point. He has just covered epsilon delta definition. So, I want to use that here.

Comment: If the question comes from an introductory book in calculus, I think that your answer may not help.